# What does the following C++ code snipped do?

Tags: c++, oop, reference, type-conversion

Assume A is a user-defined type.

```
A ob1;
A ob2 = (A&) ob1;
```

What is now ob2? 
I saw the above code in a project, and I was wondering what is the purpose of it. Is it a faster way to copy the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast is meaningless. A copy of the object is still made in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It is meaningless. Someone probably saw the assignment operator defined as

```
A& A::operator=(const A& other)
```

and assumed that they would have to cast it to work.

Comment: Assignment operator is not used here, though. In general, `T x = y;` is equivalent to `T x(T(y));`, so OPs code is `A ob2(A(ob1));`; this is just copy-constructor.